# Ending char* vector in c

Tags: c

How do I mark the end of a char* vector with '\0' to null-terminate it?
If i have char* vector:

```
 char* param[5];
```

I thought of either

```
 param[4] = '\0';
```

or

```
char c = '\0';
param[4] = &c;
```

but none of them seem to work?

param is a char-pointer vector, supposed to point to 5 strings(char-vectors).

Comment: What do you mean by 'securing a vector'?

Comment: char* param[5] = { "one","two","three","four","five strings" };

Comment: This isn't a vector (STL's std::vector) but rather an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok you are trying to end a vector of strings, something similar to what is passed to `main` as `argv`. In that case you just need to assign a null pointer:

```
param[4] = 0;
```

Comment: yes, like argv. so '\0' won't work in this case, because it describes value, not adress???

Comment: what is surprising is that `param[4] = '\0'`; should also work (even if the intent is mixed up) but the OP said it didn't.

Comment: @Rotor, on the machine level, `'\0'` is equivalent to `0`. However, for (at least some) compilers, the former is a `char` value, not a legal pointer value. Of course, you could cast it to pointer as `(char*)'\0'` - this would technically work, but is ugly and much more complicated than a plain `0`.

Comment: @Péter: `'\0'` is a character constant which in C has type `int`, not `char`.

Comment: "(at least some) compilers" in this case means "C++ compilers", whereas the question is about C.

Answer (score 1):

If you really have an array of `char*`, you can do:

```
 param[4] = "";
```

(Your second approach actually should work as long as you don't need `param[4]` to be valid when `c` goes out of scope.)

A better sentinel value usually would be the null pointer, however:

```
 param[4] = NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

A `char*` vector is a vector of pointer to chars. You probably want a vector of char. In that case, you could write:

```
char vect[5] = { '\0' };
```

In this way the vector is initialized with all `'\0'` characters.

If you really want an array of char pointer you can do similarly:

```
char* vect[5] = { NULL };
```

All pointers to string will be initialized with `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably write something like below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    char* param[5] = {"1", "2", "3", "4", NULL};

    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; param[i] ; i++){
       printf("%s\n", param[i]);
    }
```

}

Instead of NULL I could use 0, or '\0' as all are the same in the end (numerical value 0), but I believe using the NULL macro capture best the intention.

You can also write `param[4] = NULL;` if it's done after the initialization, and you `param[4] = '\0';` should have worked (but looks more like obfuscation as you don't want a char at all, but a NULL pointer)

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
char* param[5];
```

vector cannot be 'null terminated' - it is a vector of char pointers. You can only null terminate arrays of chars (by putting a `'\0'` whereever you want to terminate the char array.

Hence, I guess the correct answer to your question would be [mu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_(negative)): Your question cannot be answered because it's based on incorrect assumptions. :-)